# How to kill camera process in iPhone through our app

Tags: ios, camera

I want to disable the camera functionality in all apps when we  turn off the button in our app.

Comment: Not Possible with iOS

Comment: An app cannot have any effect over any other app or settings that control those other apps.

Comment: You can only in your app close the camera which is called up by your app.

Comment: Thank u . Please elaborate your  answer .

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You cannot disable other apps camera from your app.